# Macbook not detecting all USB keyboard keys

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb, hardware, power-management

I have a Macbook Pro 2019. I recently purchase the Corsair K68 RGB keyboard which has a common USB Type-A connector. I used OTG for USB A to USB C.
The first time mac detects the new device. Worked great.
When I disconnected and reconnected the keyboard it only detects keys from A-Z. Not even spacebar or num keys.
Tried going to keyboard settings >> Change Keyboard Type. It does not detect my keyboard.

It only starts to work again when I restarted my mac. Now every time if my keyboard unplugged accidentally, I have to restart my mac.

Is there any other way to do it without restarting macbook again and again everytime?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you're using an [On-The-Go adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go).

> USB OTG introduces the concept of a device performing both master and slave roles – whenever two USB devices are connected and one of them is a USB OTG device, they establish a communication link. The device controlling the link is called the master or host, while the other is called the slave or peripheral.

The OTG adapter is designed to allow your device to switch roles of being the host or peripheral; this is necessary to connect devices such as mobile phones to devices like flash drives and keyboards because your mobile device has to be both -  a host when you plug in a keyboard and a peripheral when you plug it into a computer.

There's no need for this swapping of roles when you plug things into your computer as it will always be the host and whatever you plug into it will always be the peripheral.  Even your phone won't be a host to a computer.  The computer will always see it as an external device; maybe a storage device or even a camera.

What you should be using is just a plain USB-C to USB-A adapter/converter - I like and have used [Anker adapters](http://radnex.us/Anker-USB-C_to_USB-A_Adapter) due to their quality and warranty. (I have about a half dozen of these everywhere from my briefcase and my desk).  You don't need anything expensive, but make sure you get from a known brand (this is not the time to save a couple dollars).  When plugging in a sub $10 item into a $2,000+ computer, I tend err on the side of caution and go with reputable names.

Comment: I have the plain USB-C to USB-A adapter. I thought of it and actually bought 3 of them. Facing same issue with all of them. I don't think its an OTG issue since my other peripheral works great with each of them

Answer (score -1):

I have seen instances where USB ports stop working, but that's mostly been due to a static discharge on my part.

In a situation like this, the first thing I would do is see if the keyboard works without issue in another computer, with and without the OTG cable.  I would also see if you can use a different USB-A to USB-C adapter.

Another thing to check on is the System Profiler to see if the keyboard is being recognized properly. This way, you can try and rule out if it's the computer, the adapter, or the keyboard.

I hope it helps.